# Book recomendation for affine geometry

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, book-recommendation

Which books are recomended to start studying affine differential geometry? I only know of Affine Differential Geometry by Su Buchin.

Comment: A classic is the second volume of Blaschke’s Lectures on Differential Geometry.